# Accesing app state inside a function

Tags: react-native, mobile, react-redux

I'm currently building up a mobile app using React-Native with React-Redux. Is there a way to access a Redux state (getState()) from within a function that's not in a component?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html), there are two ways you can use the AppState.

1. Accessing `AppState.currentState` to get the current state (kept updated).
2. Adding an event listener to the changes to AppState through `AppState.addEventListener(type, handler)`.

If you need it once, use the first one. However, if you need to check for changes use the second.

Comment: Sorry, I was refering to a redux state, I updated the question and marked it as duplicate. Thanks.